# Declined “Very Low Quality” flag on a duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63091920/12867493) (now deleted) as Very Low Quality (contents of the post as it got deleted):

> It's not compulsory to have a list.

My flag got declined as:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

[Reasons why answers may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) are (emphasis mine):

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - **exact duplicates of other answers**
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The other answer states the same but in more detail (emphasis mine):

> **You do not have to include that list**, and it wouldn't change the database structure under the hood. Having that list is only for comfort, enabling you to execute queries using the courses list of an instructor.

So this answer doesn’t add any value.

The community also agrees this should be deleted, this answer got [2 *recommended deletion* reviews in the Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26780424) queue.

So why was my flag declined?

Comment: what's the relation between VLQ and that an answer should be deleted? ... I agree it should be downvoted and deleted but it's not a VLQ

Comment: @TemaniAfif VLQ is the appropriate flag in these situations

Comment: no, there is no need for a flag here. You need to downvote the answer

Comment: Even if the answer were: *"U dont gotta have no lsit"* I wouldn't flag it as VLQ. Sure, it's terrible, but comprehensible, and it does attempt to answer the question. OTOH, I wouldn't waste energy editing it, unless it didn't duplicate an existing answer.

Comment: Please do not use the VLQ flag on answers for anything other than gibberish, Link only answers or Non English posts. If it is a duplicate answer, use a custom moderator flag to indicate that it is a duplicate and specify clearly as to what the original post is.

Comment: Just for the records: The wording is "**exact** duplicates of other answers". Exact as in copy-paste of another answer. Answers that cover the same ground but with different words are not automatically VLQ. This answer is bad and should be downvoted. But it's not an exact copy of some other answer.

Comment: What works for me to get these duplicate answers deleted is: 1) to downvote such an answer so it has a -1 score (20k+ users can delete such answers), 2) comment under it with an explanation why this answer has no value and a link to an older answer(s) with the same information; 3) post a del-pls request in SOCVR. I used custom mod flags before a lot previously for these answers and in the end a mod contacted me and asked to stop doing that.

Answer (score 17):

The "very low quality" flag doesn't mean "this answer is a duplicate of another answer". It means:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

The answer you flagged did not meet these criteria. There were no formatting problems whatsoever, and the content was fine. It provided a direct answer to the question that was asked.

The answer you flagged was not eligible for either "very low quality" or "not an answer" flags.

(For what it's worth, I *strongly* considered review-banning the users who recommended deletion of that answer. There's no cause for it being deleted via review. It is a valid answer in every way.)

Moderators do not review all of the other answers on the question when handling "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags. That's simply not a reasonable expectation. If you want to tell us that an answer is a duplicate of another answer on the Q&A and thus adds no value, then you should raise a custom moderator flag and provide us a link to the other answer to consider.

Comment: "Content was fine"

Comment: Yes, the content was fine. And no, I'm not going to read 20 other answers just to get "context". You (presumably) already did that, so just provide that information in the flag.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that the reviewers went through the other questions, then saw this was a duplicate, and then recommended deletion?