# Duplicate answers in Low Quality Answers: (Re-)Flag or Delete?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-answers, custom-flags, low-quality-answers

A couple of months ago, a moderator reminded me not to use the *NAA* flag for duplicate answers (thank you):

> helpful - This is an answer. A "Not an Answer" flag is inappropriate. It may be a duplicate answer. It may be primarily a "worked for me" answer, but those need explanation, which should be in a custom flag.

[Cody Gray ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) offered [similar guidance here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399786/3025856) previously. I've since adhered to this.

***My question:*** If I see a duplicate answer in the *LQA* queue, should I:

1. (Vote to) Delete
2. (Re-)Flag for moderator attention
3. All of the above

> *Note:* Regardless, in these cases, I usually leave a comment explaining to both the author and future reviewers that the answer is a duplicate, and linking to the answer it duplicates.

***Consideration:*** Even beyond the rationale for not using the *NAA* flag, answers deleted via the *LQA* queue are subject to becoming audits. While reviewers *should* be looking for duplicate answers, they're very difficult to spot via audits since both comments and other answers are hidden in that scenario.

This makes me think that we *should* be (re-)flagging but *not* voting to delete (i.e., skipping). Is that a fair conclusion? Or is that just adding noise for moderators when these posts would likely end up getting deleted by the *LQA* review process anyway?

Comment: If I understand correctly both the response you've quoted and Cody Gray's answer. It seems that the appropriate review response would be "Looks OK". Given that posts enter LQA (mostly) through either NAA or VLQ flags and those flags should be declined. A custom flag would have to happen outside of queue since there's no "flag" option in LQA.

Comment: @HenryEcker: I think that's a compelling argument. The one potential caveat—as I've been reminded a few times, and often struggle with—is that the rubrics for _NAA_ ≠_LQA_. I.e., _NAA_ flags should be used exclusively for the narrow criteria of non-answers, whereas reviewers are _expected_ to exercise more judgment in reviewing _LQA_. Historically, I've been voting to delete duplicates—but based on both my question and now your comment, I'm definitely second-guessing that response.

Comment: Total aside, I'm really happy I saw the moderator comment on that flag, as they're easy to miss, and especially when you've potentially flagged hundreds of posts since. There's an old [meta-tag:feature-request] on Meta Stack Exchange to [get notified when a moderator comments on a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172262/add-a-notification-on-moderator-comments-on-flags), for anyone interested.

Comment: It's just me, but I don't see the need for the distinction here. If I see a bad post that unambiguously doesn't contribute anything at all and that needs to be removed anyway, and it comes up in the queue because someone else flagged it for removal, and I'm given the choice to help that process along or say that the post is OK - saying that it's OK and then flagging to require intervention by a ♦ seems like a total waste. If I'd vote to delete something irredeemable outside the queue, it seems it'd be easier for all involved to also vote to delete inside the queue.

Comment: That doesn't mean that duplicate answers should be *flagged* as NAA/VLQ, but if they happen to come up while reviewing, and the reviewers happen to deal with it without additional headaches - why not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given the current guidelines it seems the only correct response for LQA queue is "Looks OK" (or "Edit" if needed).

According to [How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality):

> - **Recommend deletion or Delete** if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible. Do not vote to delete answers that are simply wrong. You may leave a comment explaining the issues with the answer, or choose one of the provided canned comments.

The only reasons to choose Delete is if "an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible". Assuming the duplicate answer does not meet these criteria, then the only options within the queue that remain are "Edit" and "Looks OK".

This sentiment is echoed in [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399786/15497888):

> (For what it's worth, I *strongly* considered review-banning the users who recommended deletion of that answer. There's no cause for it being deleted via review. It is a valid answer in every way.)

Confirming that "Delete" is most certainly not the correct response.

To be extra diligent and work beyond the queue, one *can* look through other posts to check for things like duplicate answers and flag for moderator attention, but this is not part of the LQA queue requirements.

---

**Note** this differs from Late Answers Queue where the [deletion guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers) reads:

> - **Delete (or recommend deletion of)** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.

Here "duplicates of other answers" *is* a valid deletion reason.

Comment: This is an excellent response, and a compelling argument why it shouldn't be both (re-)flagged _and_ deleted. I especially appreciate the differentiation between the _LQA_ and _LA_ queues, as I often find myself jumbling the rubrics when jumping between the _LQA_, _LA_, and _FA_ queues. Of course, don't _Late Answers_ that are voted for deletion just end up in _LQA_ anyway? If so, the _workflow_ here is confusing, even if the _guidance_ is not.

Comment: According to the [updated review queue map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5x7.png) from  [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) Late Answers that are recommended to be deleted never end up in LQA queue, they are simply deleted when they reach the threshold. No workflow issue in that regard.

Comment: You've convinced me. I've started following this guidance in my own reviews—and will reference your answer when I see reviewers recommending deletion for duplicate answers (which is a fairly common occurrence). If there are any concerns with this, then it sounds like we need to update the guidance/FAQs for the _LQA_ queue. Until then, I'll consider this the appropriate and expected handling. Thank you for your diligence in addressing my ambivalence.

Comment: I agree if the duplicate answers should be handled in LQA queue then the guidelines would need to be updated. We'd also somehow need to extend either the definition of NAA or VLQ flags to encompass duplicates (as they do not currently do so). Somewhat related: there is a feature-request [How about adding a "duplicate answer" manual flag type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398644/15497888) which has [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412641/15497888) that proposes a way to implement either a separate duplicated answers queue or somehow integrate it into LQA.

Comment: Note that the help center was a copy paste from a post on meta, which was flawed to begin with. That's why there are gaps. It's not that the guidance needs to consider this, it's that it never did. The whole thing isn't a guidance, but more of a laundry list that some users took with how people used the queues.

Comment: Yikes. I'll make sure to not Recommend Delete on these from now on then unless the guidance changes. Still, from a semantics point of view, I don't feel like I can say "Looks OK" on something I know is bad and should be removed for other reasons (plagiarism/rudeness). To me, I feel like I'm saying, "Yes, this plagiarized answer 'Looks OK.'" I guess I'll just re-flag and Skip.

Comment: Also, how do we deal with "<copy-paste someone else's code without attribution> worked for me." Does that count as a Thank-you Comment? I see reviewers choose that a lot.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz: I also struggle with that gray area between plagiarism, a duplicate answer, and a "thank you" post. Sometimes it's really ambiguous, and especially if the syntax or variable names vary slightly.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Wait, the text under "Looks OK" says "This is an **honest** attempt at answering the question and is not low quality." (Emphasis added), so there's no way "Looks OK" is correct for plagiarism. I guess Skip is the only good option here.